# How to retrieve Data Annotation Alias("tablename") and Alias("field name") from ServiceStack ORMLite?

Tags: c#, servicestack, data-annotations, ormlite-servicestack

I need to return the alias from the Data Annotation of this class "tblAccounts" and "AccountNumber". It uses ServiceStack ORM Lite.

```
[Alias("tblAccounts")]
    [Schema("task")]
    public class Account : IHasId<int>
    {
        [Alias("AccountNumber")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int OldAccountNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query this from OrmLite's `ModelDefinition` that's created for every POCO Table, e.g:

```
var modelDef = typeof(Account).GetModelMetadata();

var tableName = modelDef.ModelName;
var idName = modelDef.PrimaryKey.FieldName;
```

Which in both cases will return the `[Alias]` if it exists.

Comment: I am using my Model classes in the client application, in this case I don't use them with OrmLite SQL Server, but I reuse the same classes to load them from MS Access (manually with OLEDB), as I have this replication tool that I am creating and I don't want to declare again the same model classes.... But in my client application I don't want to declare the assembly "ORMLITE" with is required for the method .GetModelMetadata(), how can I pass the tablename and id to my client application not declaring any ORMLITE references?

Comment: @RogerOliveira Then you need to use reflection to get the attributes at runtime, e.g. `typeof(Account).GetCustomAttributes()`

Comment: @mythz Is that implying that the ModelMetadata was not retrieved using reflection?

Comment: @glazjoon it’s created using reflection, then cached to avoid any runtime reflection and should be considered immutable after Startup.